# Use Tags in exported XML from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I have the following problem.

I want to convert data from a mysql database to XML. Actually I do this with the command:

```
mysql --xml -i -u username -p tablename 'select * from performancedata LIMIT 10'> query.xml;
```

The output looks like this:

```
<resultset statement="select * from performancedata LIMIT 10
" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <row>
    <field name="time">2017-05-20 18:04:14</field>
    <field name="verbrauch">329</field>
    <field name="leistung">759</field>
    <field name="einspeisung">430</field>
    <field name="avgEinspeisung">0</field>
</row>
```

....

So that I can parse this XML, I have to convert the tags  to the column names e.g. time = . How can I do this best?

I need the following format:

```
<row>
    <time>2017-05-20 18:04:14</time>
    <verbrauch>329</verbrauch>
    <leistung>759</leistung>
    <einspeisung>430</einspeisung>
    <avgEinspeisung>0</avgEinspeisung>
</row>
```

Comment: With PHP: I guess you could try using [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) - load query result into one SimpleXML object, then iterate over `row`'s children and write new xml while naming each `field` child as attribute dictates.

Answer (score 0):

How exactly are you getting this data out of MySQL?  Are you literally running a command line command from within PHP to get the outputted XML?  Or does your command line example show how you are doing it from the command line and now you want to figure out how to do it from within PHP?

Either way, I think your best bet, rather than relying on MySQL to manage the conversion to XML for you, is to convert it yourself and simply use MySQL as the data store that it is meant to be.  You could use [simplexmlelement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) to manage the conversion to XML but for a simple example like this it is conceptually easier to just build the xml yourself.  If you are using something like PDO for your database connection it would look something like this:

```
$qres = $pdo->query( "select * from performancedata LIMIT 10" );
$xml = '<row>';
foreach ( $qres->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) as $row )
{
    foreach ( $row as $name => $value )
        $xml .= "    <$name>$value</$name>";
}
$xml .= '</row>';

print $xml;
```